# Bash init - start service under specific user

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, init

I am trying to create an init script in bash (Ubuntu) that starts a service under a specific user.

Is there a better way to do that other than this?

```
su - <user>  -c "bash -c  'cd $DIR ;<service name>'"
```

Comment: If an answer answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 20):

Ubuntu uses `start-stop-daemon` which already supports this feature.

Use the skeleton file from /etc/init.d:

`sudo cp /etc/init.d/skeleton /etc/init.d/mynewservice`

Edit mynewservice appropriately.

Add the following parameter to the lines that call start-stop-daemon:

`--chuid username:group`

Example:

Change

`start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \`

to

`start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid someuser:somegroup --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \`

Finally, register your service and start it:

`update-rc.d mynewservice defaults 99 && service mynewservice start`

More info about other options for start-stop-daemon [here](http://man.he.net/man8/start-stop-daemon)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use the `daemon` function defined in your `/etc/init.d/functions` file:

```
daemon --user=<user> $DIR/program
```

If you look into its syntax you can do other things like defining PID file location, setting nice level, and whatnot. It's otherwise really useful for starting up services as daemons. Services started up with `daemon` can easily be terminated by another functions function, `killproc`.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I'm running into is that it's a process that needs to be run from a particular directory but the process itself isn't actually in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script under `/etc/init.d/` say your_service_name, with minimal contents

`#!/bin/sh`
`su - <user>  -c "bash -c  'cd $DIR ;<service name>'"`

Provide appropriate permission to the script. Now use `update-rc.d` command in the required `/etc/rc<run_level>.d` directory to create a soft link for your script so that the script is run when system starts with the mentioned run level.
Please refer scripts under `/etc/init.d/` for reference &  please go through `/etc/init.d/README` for more details regarding writing the script. Man page for `update-rc.d` will also help to find out about the usage of `update-rc.d`. This definitely works on Ubuntu machine I use, but I'm guessing that this facility will be available across distros.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by

1. Create bash script and put it in /etc/init.d/ using following pattern
    `#!/bin/bash`
    `su <user> -c "bash -c '<path to service> $1'"`
2. Setup run codes for the script using the following command
    `sudo update-rc.d <my_scrpit> defaults`

Once this script is set in run codes, upon restarting, root run the script and will pass start/stop to the script as $1, depending on the status of the run mode.
If you want to test your script without restarting you should run it as root and pass the service action e.g. start/stop/restart.... 
     `root# ./etc/init.d/my_scrpit start`

Comment: I tried to apply it in Ubuntu 16.04 in `/etc/rc.local`, but my test script didn't execute:
`su -l user -c "bash /home/user/bin/start_check"`. The script expected to write some logs.